# Windows batch file to start and stop service for different users

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-command-prompt

I am having an Admin account that wanted to run a batch file that will start and stop a few services for different users.(Wanted to perform from the same server)

For example, what I wanted to do is CMD run as username password net start service.exe

Can you guide to use the correct formation of the commands

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a logon script but not as the current user](https://serverfault.com/questions/435745) or [any from this search](https://serverfault.com/search?q=%5Bwindows%5D+logon+script)?

Answer (score 1):

> ... start and stop a few services for different users.

That's *not* how Windows Services work.
You define a Service and, as part of that definition, you set the account that it will run under, usually a system one.
That's it.

You *cannot* have multiple instances of a Windows Service running under different accounts (well, you *could*, but each and every Service * User combination would to be installed as *its own* Service!)

You *can* run processes (executables) under different accounts, but they would not be Windows Services.  As such, "net start" cannot help you.